# special (not-found) page dos not work in (route-groups) in next13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, file-not-found

I want to create special not-found page in my (next13) project that I have route-groups. and in any route-group I have separate (layout) page. my not-found page is this but dos not work and the default 404 page shows:
[image URL] => (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzA1O.png)

I try to create (not-found) page aside layout page, my expecting is if I do not have any URL, show this (not-found) page Instead default 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that needs to create (layout) file in (app) folder. and it can just return (children) component.
after that we should to create (not-found) page aside this layout.
and done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).